# R: Multiple matches when one includes another

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, text-mining

I'm trying to extract "Maya is ,. nice" from the string written below ("" are not part of the string):

"something ransom Maya wants to go for dinner with Shawn Maya is ,. nice"

However, I keep getting "Maya wants to go for dinner with Shawn Maya is ,. nice" which is not what I was looking for.

Any insights? I'm using stringr in R

Comment: Can you share the part of code you are using?

Comment: What are you looking for? @akrun 's answer does exactly what you have mentioned in your question. May be your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option in `base R` where we match the word 'Maya' followed by 'is' and other characters (.`*) till the end (`$`) of the string, capture as a group (`(...)`) and replace with the backreference (`\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*\\b(Maya is .*$)", "\\1", str1)
#1] "Maya is ,. nice"
```

---

Or with `regexpr/regmatches`

```
regmatches(str1, regexpr("Maya is .*$", str1))
#[1] "Maya is ,. nice"
```

---

Or with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "Maya is .*$")
```

NOTE: The Op's expected output is already showed in the post

#### data

```
str1 <- "something ransom Maya wants to go for dinner with Shawn Maya is ,. nice"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! What do I change in str_extract if there are other characters after "nice"?

Comment: @Gillian  You don't have to change anything as `.*$` impliees characters till the end (`$`) of the string